# MongoDB - Get data in date sections from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am new to MongoDB, I want to get data in sections from the array.

```
{
   "name":"User name",
   "messages":[
      {
         "message":"Message 1",
         "date":"2022-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
         "message":"Message 2",
         "date":"2022-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
         "message":"Message 3",
         "date":"2022-05-13T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
         "message":"Message 4",
         "date":"2022-05-13T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
         "message":"Message 5",
         "date":"2022-05-13T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

The results I want are

```
[
   {
      "date":"2022-05-12T00:00:00.000Z",
      "messages":[
         {
            "message":"Message 1",
            "date":"2022-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         {
            "message":"Message 2",
            "date":"2022-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "date":"2022-05-13T00:00:00.000Z",
      "messages":[
         {
            "message":"Message 3",
            "date":"2022-05-13T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         {
            "message":"Message 4",
            "date":"2022-05-13T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         {
            "message":"Message 5",
            "date":"2022-05-13T00:00:00.000Z"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm not familiar with MongoDB aggregation, I have looked at many questions on stack overflow but didn't find any that helped me.

Is this possible to do? If yes **any help would be greatly appreciated. :)**

Comment: Hi Najam, I had problem like your question how you solve retrieve data by date inside of array element.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation to get your desired output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$messages"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$messages.date",
      messages: {
        $push: "$messages"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: "$_id",
      messages: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `messages` array to multiple documents.
2. `$group` - Group by `messages.date` and add `messages` document into `messages` array.
3. `$project` - Decorate output documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$messages"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$messages.date",
      messages: {
        $push: "$messages"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: "$_id",
      messages: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_q6I8y7kvpY)

Comment: Corrected should be `date: "$_id"` not `date: "$_id.date"`. Sorry for the typo.